# Main activity with bottom navigation to another fragment with bottom navigation

Tags: java, android

Sorry for the vague question. But I'm stuck and I need help. I have this Activity which is my Main and it has bottom navigation with 4 fragments and I have another fragment named Book fragment that also has bottom navigation that hosted 3 fragments. Now in my second fragment from my Main activity, there's a recycler view with click listener. What I want to achieve is after clicking the item from the recycler view it will go to my Book fragment. But my problem now is, the bottom navigation in my book fragment didn't replace the bottom navigation from the main activity. Any guide on how can I achieve this?

Comment: just clear the mainActivity's backstack will do

Comment: Is BookFragment is attach to mainActivity?

Comment: @KGeeks No, it is not attached.

Comment: than attach BookFragment to new activty (EX. BookActivity) & open it above the mainActivity.